# How to remove unused code from Linux .so files?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have binaries X, Y, Z, and they use libA.so, libB.so and libD.so (as printed by `ldd`). Is there a tool which makes the libA.so, libB.so and libD.so files smaller by removing all symbols (and the associated code and data) which is not used by any of X, Y and Z? I don't have access to the source code of the programs or the .so files.

I think I've seen such an .so stripping tool a few years ago, but I forgot the details.

Comment: the program is `strip`

Comment: But this does not remove code and data.

Comment: `libA.so` could be used by some other application, so you should not alter it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: No, this instance of `libA.so` is not and will not be used by any application other than X, Y and Z on this system. I'm 100% sure that I do want to alter it.

Comment: @suspectus: I don't think it's possible to do it with strip. If you think so, please give me the command line which contains X, Y, Z, libA.so, libB.so and libD.so.

Answer (score 2):

I've just found [Library Optimizer](http://libraryopt.sourceforge.net/config.html), but it needs the original .o object files from which libA.so etc. was built.

I've also found [mklibs](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/devel/mklibs). It also needs .o files, e.g. `/lib/libc_pic.a`. But it's very convenient to use, and installation is also easy: `sudo apt-get install mklibs`. Please note that most shared libraries don't have a precompiled `*_pic.a`, so there will be no size savings.

Comment: Be careful with `mklibs` as it may remove dlopened libraries (loaded "manually" by applications) because it doesn't see them.